# ChromeDriver.exe stopped working after patching on my Windows Remote Server

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

ChromeDriver.exe has stopped working after patching on my Windows Remote server

These updates were installed

KB3018238,KB3175443,KB3177723

I have tried all the means including turning off DEP and IP virtualization but it's not working, When I run my remote Jenkins jobs

Comment: How is the slave connected to Jenkins?

Comment: There is no slave..it's not the master itself